# Getting error in pom.xml while creating dependency for xml unit

Tags: maven

I want to compare two `XML` files using `xmlunit` but while trying to create dependency for the same in maven I'm getting an error in `pom.xml`

I used below dependency code but the jar files are not downloaded.
Tried below code in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
<groupId> xmlunit  </groupId>
<artifactId>  xmlunit  </artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I want to download the jar files of XMLunit using maven

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about white space in groupId and artifactId. 
I suppose that this code should working:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
  <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Run you project by using this command

```
mvn clean install
```

or

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

if u want to download this single dependency by using maven run this command

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version
```

Comment: I tried still the jar files are not present in xmlunit in .m2 folder.